# Haskell function composition

Tags: function, haskell, composition

I've defined a function f1 and f2,so that I can use at the and the function composition (`fkomp`), which is supposed to use f1 and f2 to calculate `2^x` by every element in a given List.

```
f1 :: Int -> Int 
f1 x = product (replicate x 2)

f2 :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
f2 f xs = [f x | x <- xs]

fkomp :: [Int] -> [Int]        
fkomp xs = f2 f1 $ xs
```

It works,but the problem is,that i can't write my code with composition:

```
fkomp xs = f2.f1 $ xs
```

I've been typing every single combination but it doesn't work with composition.

Could someone lighten my path ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Whom are you referring to as Asena?

Comment: @AaditMShah ... I guess him/herself ;)

Comment: Oh, the OP's name is Vucic Asena. Punctuation please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, let's look just at the types (it's like a puzzle - the types have to fit):

```
f1 :: Int -> Int
f2 :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b] = (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

in order to compose the both you need ones co-domain to be the same as the others domain.

This is because the composition has type:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

See the `b` has to fit ;)

So for your `f1` and `f2` you would need either `Int ~ (a -> b)` or `Int ~ ([a] -> [b])` both of which are not working well (as you found out).

**BUT** you kind of have the ability to **apply** `f1` to `f2` as `f1` just fits `f2` first argument (as you have seen too) - so I am a bit confused why you even want to use composition here.

#### remarks

your functions are a bit strange - I think the usual way to write them would be

```
f1 x = 2 ^ x
f2 = map
```

or even

```
fkomp :: [Int] -> [Int]
fkomp = map (2^)
```

note that the last one is **not** function-composition but (just as your case) function-application: I apply the function `(2^) :: Int -> Int` to `map :: (Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int]` and get a function of type `[Int] -> [Int]` as the result (if you check the types in GHCi you will see a more generic versions but I think this is a bit more clear)

Comment: Sorry i forgot, i ticked it :) Thanks a lot Carsten!